# Managing browser memory, on browser console, with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-management, garbage-collection

How managing memory log ("garbage collection") on browser console?, in the same way as you do manually on Firefox's `about:memory` page.

It would be useful to have a method (for browser console) to force **CC/GC/Minimize Memory** without having to load `about:memory`.